# Flex Children to Shrink if required otherwise grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a Calendar displaying various events. I want the eventContainer div's to shrink when they are clashing otherwise be **left aligned and grow to 90% of the date container width.**

How do I achieve this?

Exact problem in example below: I want Event 3 & 4 to display like Event 5.

```css
.master {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #FCFBF8;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.dateContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.eventContainer {
  border: 1px solid #8EB094;
  background-color: #0B8043;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  max-width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  height: 46px
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="dateContainer">
    <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 40px">
      <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 30px">
      <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dateContainer">
    <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 10px">
      <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 90px">
      <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dateContainer">
    <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 30px">
      <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your HTML/CSS snippet to include a wrapper `div` with class "row", and the `.dateContainer` now has `flex-direction` as `column` to allow child elements to flow vertically. In case they collide, they'll shrink to 50%, courtesy the `flex` CSS for each `.eventContainer`.

The clashing events should be wrapped in a single `.row` div.

```css
.master {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #FCFBF8;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.dateContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  /* update to whatever the initial flex-basis you want for the containers */
  flex-basis: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1; 
}

.eventContainer {
  border: 1px solid #8EB094;
  background-color: #0B8043;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  max-width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  height: 46px
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="dateContainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 40px">
        <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 30px">
        <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dateContainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 10px">
        <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 90px">
        <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dateContainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="eventContainer" style="top: 30px">
        <p style="color:white; margin: 0;">Event 5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kanishk. It makes sense in general but I will still have to calculate the clashing events i.e run a function to check which events will overlap. I wanted to avoid doing that. I thought just by CSS if I can control it then it will save me unnecessary function runs.

Comment: @user3884753 I am not sure if pure CSS can help you figure it out. If you have 2 children in a flexbox and have content, they're bound to take some width. Problem is `.dateContainer` itself gets divided into 2 if you have 2 children and then take the relevant space. You can ideally add some class to "clashing" events to reduce their width, but you'll anyways need to figure out those events using JS.

Comment: Yup, doing that now